# How to decrease time it takes to benchmark?

Tags: benchmarking, weight

I have the following benchmark that takes a very long time to complete. What measures can I take to improve the time it takes to run the benchmark without losing its effectiveness?

```rust
on_initialize {
        let m in 1 .. 3_000;
        for j in 0 .. m {
            let mortality_block = 49 as u32;
            let sig = generate_test_signature();
            assert_ok!(Msa::<T>::register_signature(&sig, T::BlockNumber::from(mortality_block)));
        }

        let bucket_zero_iter = PayloadSignatureRegistry::<T>::iter_prefix(T::BlockNumber::from(0u32));
        assert_eq!(bucket_zero_iter.count(), m as usize);
    }: {
        Msa::<T>::on_initialize(100u32.into());
    } verify {
        let bucket_zero_iter = PayloadSignatureRegistry::<T>::iter_prefix(T::BlockNumber::from(0u32));
        assert_eq!(bucket_zero_iter.count(), 0 as usize);
    }
```

Running with the following configurations:

- --steps 50
- --repeat 10

Comment: I think the only way is low down the `steps` and `repeat`. Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: What is slow about it? Generating the signatures?

Comment: Good point. I am going to dive a litter deeper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked your code and the signature generation is very slow.
However, the signatures are never verified so you can get away by mocking them which is million times faster.
First lets increase the `3_000` to `50_000` for a larger effect. Then get rid of the `generate_test_signature` function and mock the signature.

```rust
let m in 1 .. 50_000;
for j in 0 .. m {
    let mut sig = [0u8; 64];
    sig[0..8].copy_from_slice(&(m, j).encode());
    let sig = MultiSignature::Sr25519(sp_core::sr25519::Signature::from_raw(sig));

    let mortality_block = 49 as u32;
    assert_ok!(Msa::<T>::register_signature(&sig, T::BlockNumber::from(mortality_block)));
}
```

PS: Running the benchmark tests with `--release` also helps.

Please **always** include source code links to your questions and an elaborate explanation of the problem, thanks.